# Solve taking too long to solve an equation

Tags: equation-solving

For a more general problem, I obtain the following function that I labelled $f(x)$ in Mathematica.

```
f[x_] := 
  (3.`/((1 + 10 Sqrt[x])^0.4` Sqrt[x]) + 3.15`/
    ((11 + 10.5` Sqrt[x])^0.4` Sqrt[x])) * 
  (1 + 10 Sqrt[x])^0.6` (14 + 20.5` Sqrt[x])/
    (2 ((1 + 10 Sqrt[x])^0.6` + (11 + 10.5` Sqrt[x])^0.6`)^2)
```

I can plot this function and find its value for specific values of `x` (e.g., `f[3] = -0.812092` ). But when I try to evaluate

```
Solve[f[x] == -0.812092, x]
```

Mathematica keeps running for a very long time until I abort the evaluation.
I would like to know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome! `NSolve` returns a solution quite quickly... Please note that you have machine numbers in your function definition, which in additon of the fairly gnarly function may be one reason for the hang-up, as `Solve` will search for generic (symbolic) solutions

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Your function seems to be positive for real `x>0`.
Using `Solve[f[x] == -0.812092, x]` you try to find a general complex solution!

If you're only interested in real solution try

```
 NSolve[{f[x] == -.81, x > 0}, x, Reals]
 (*{}*)
```